# Pandas drop before first valid index and after last valid index for each column of a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'timestamp':pd.date_range('2018-01-01', '2018-01-02', freq='2h', closed='right'),'col1':[np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,np.nan], 'col2':[np.nan, np.nan, 0, 1,2,3,4,5,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan], 'col3':[np.nan, -1, 0, 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9], 'col4':[-2, -1, 0, 1,2,3,4,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan]
              })[['timestamp', 'col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4']]
```

which looks like this:

```
             timestamp  col1  col2  col3  col4
0  2018-01-01 02:00:00   NaN   NaN   NaN  -2.0
1  2018-01-01 04:00:00   NaN   NaN  -1.0  -1.0
2  2018-01-01 06:00:00   NaN   0.0   NaN   0.0
3  2018-01-01 08:00:00   1.0   1.0   1.0   1.0
4  2018-01-01 10:00:00   2.0   NaN   2.0   2.0
5  2018-01-01 12:00:00   3.0   3.0   NaN   3.0
6  2018-01-01 14:00:00   NaN   4.0   4.0   4.0
7  2018-01-01 16:00:00   5.0   NaN   5.0   NaN
8  2018-01-01 18:00:00   6.0   NaN   6.0   NaN
9  2018-01-01 20:00:00   7.0   NaN   7.0   NaN
10 2018-01-01 22:00:00   8.0   NaN   8.0   NaN
11 2018-01-02 00:00:00   NaN   NaN   9.0   NaN
```

Now, I want to find an efficient and pythonic way of chopping off (for each column! Not counting timestamp) before the first valid index and after the last valid index. In this example I have 4 columns, but in reality I have a lot more, 600 or so. I am looking for a way of chop of all the NaN values before the first valid index and all the NaN values after the last valid index.

One way would be to loop through I guess.. But is there a better way? This way has to be efficient. I tried to "unpivot" the dataframe using melt, but then this didn't help.

An obvious point is that each column would have a different number of rows after the chopping. So I would like the result to be a list of data frames (one for each column) having timestamp and the column in question. For instance:

```
             timestamp  col1   
3  2018-01-01 08:00:00   1.0  
4  2018-01-01 10:00:00   2.0   
5  2018-01-01 12:00:00   3.0   
6  2018-01-01 14:00:00   NaN   
7  2018-01-01 16:00:00   5.0   
8  2018-01-01 18:00:00   6.0   
9  2018-01-01 20:00:00   7.0   
10 2018-01-01 22:00:00   8.0
```

**My try**

I tried like this:

```
final = []
columns = [c for c in df if c !='timestamp']
for col in columns:
    first = df.loc[:, col].first_valid_index()
    last = df.loc[:, col].last_valid_index()
    final.append(df.loc[:, ['timestamp', col]].iloc[first:last+1, :])
```

Comment: An idea that I had was using groupby but I gave up after an hour of trying..

Comment: Your current method seems to work fine. What's your main concern? Efficiency, maintainability, both?

Comment: Efficiency mainly, this is a very small example. My dataframe is massive and the problem of this method is that is uses a `for` statement. But for a large dataframe this seems to crash.. I was hoping something with groupby could solve this quicker

Answer (score 1):

One idea is to use a list or dictionary comprehension after setting your index as `timestamp`. You should test with your data to see if this resolves your issue with performance. It is unlikely to help if your limitation is memory.

```
df = df.set_index('timestamp')

final = {col: df[col].loc[df[col].first_valid_index(): df[col].last_valid_index()] \
         for col in df}

print(final)

{'col1': timestamp
2018-01-01 08:00:00    1.0
2018-01-01 10:00:00    2.0
2018-01-01 12:00:00    3.0
2018-01-01 14:00:00    4.0
2018-01-01 16:00:00    5.0
2018-01-01 18:00:00    6.0
2018-01-01 20:00:00    7.0
2018-01-01 22:00:00    8.0
Name: col1, dtype: float64,
...
'col4': timestamp
2018-01-01 02:00:00   -2.0
2018-01-01 04:00:00   -1.0
2018-01-01 06:00:00    0.0
2018-01-01 08:00:00    1.0
2018-01-01 10:00:00    2.0
2018-01-01 12:00:00    3.0
2018-01-01 14:00:00    4.0
Name: col4, dtype: float64}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the power of functional programming and apply a function to each column. This may speed things up. Also, as you `timestamps` looks sorted, you can use them as index of your Datarame.

```
df.set_index('timestamp', inplace=True)

final = []
def func(col):
    first = col.first_valid_index()
    last = col.last_valid_index()
    final.append(col.loc[first:last])
    return

df.apply(func)
```

Also, you can compact everything in a one liner:

```
final = []
df.apply(lambda col: final.append(col.loc[col.first_valid_index() : col.last_valid_index()]))
```

Answer (score 1):

My approach is to find the cumulative sum of `NaN` for each column and its inverse and filter those entries that are greater than `0`. Then I do a dict comprehension to return a dataframe for each column (you can change that to a list if that's what you prefer).

For your example we have

```
cols = [c for c in df.columns if c!='timestamp']

result_dict = {c: df[(df[c].notnull().cumsum() > 0) &
                     (df.ix[::-1,c].notnull().cumsum()[::-1] > 0)][['timestamp', c]]
               for c in cols}
```